# Value does not fall within the expected range in Excel 2013 at startup of Tool

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Error Message at start Up Excel Template + visual Studio tool office 3.0 Runtime

[image]

Comment: Please show your work and exception/error messages as a text and put some explanation about your problem.

Comment: please check image provided for exception Text .

Comment: Did you try to contact the add-in developer instead?

Comment: this is not addin application it's a workbook application

Comment: still not find any relevant answer for it